# Is there a prepaid SIM for 2 weeks in Germany?

Tags: germany, cellphones, data-plans

I consider purchasing a prepaid SIM card in Germany for **not more than 2 weeks** (although I might be in Germany for more than 2 weeks - up two two months maybe, in this trip).

I need a prepaid SIM in the midst of 1000 minutes of talking, 1000 SMSs, and up to 10GBs of web bandwidth.

Deals I found so far are around **at least one month**, but do you know a cellular provider (anbieter) in Germany that allows such plan strictly just for two weeks?

Comment: See this: https://www.prepaid-wiki.de/

Comment: Why not use your home sim for such a short visit?

Comment: While the price is usually announced per month, no provider will care if you use up all the minutes/SMS/data within two weeks. However, I have no idea how easy or hard it is to get a SIM in Germany as a foreigner because you need to prove your identity to have the SIM activated, so I'm hesitant to put this down as an answer, as your entire plan might not be feasible...

Comment: @Willeke I don't have a SIM in the country I currently I currently reside in and wouldn't make one :) Also, I might stay more than 2 weeks (maybe about a month or two - I'll edit the question to clarify just hat).

Comment: @Willeke: Because it's hella expensive (from many countries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to buy these both in the country, and from overseas.

However, as the information changes regularly, I'm going to link to the [Prepaid Wiki](https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Germany) for Germany.

Telekom has the best available coverage and speed, but o2+e-plus will be the cheapest.

Weekly rates are harder to find, you either go for daily or monthly packages.