# German SIM card for a two-week visit?

Tags: germany, cellphones, internet

I'm visiting Germany for a couple of weeks (Dresden mostly) very soon. I'm coming from outside Europe and leaving Europe after this visit.

I want to get a local SIM for my stay - mostly for Internet access but not bandwidth-heavy (no videos or large file transfer); I'll have wireless for most of my visit but not when I'm on the road. I know I *can* a SIM card, but - what's a cheap option, with decent network coverage, which I would easily find a place to buy?

<sub>PS - Unlike in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/128436/33321), I don't care if the SIM card is valid for a month or not.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Prepaid Data SIM Card Wiki has a pretty lengthy post on SIM cards for [Germany](https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Germany) (and many other countries).

As you're be staying in the city coverage on all 3 major networks [should be fine](https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Germany#SUMMARY_-_Which_network_.28and_operator.29_to_choose:), but looks like O2 is the cheapest at the cost of reliability (again, in the city it shouldn't matter that much).

You can refer to the [specific operators' pages](https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Germany#Operators) to check rates and available packages.

Also note that you will have to [register the SIM card under your name](https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Germany#1..29_registration_in_the_store_of_a_provider_.28point_of_sale_verification.29), so make sure that when you go to buy the SIM you have your passport on you.

Comment: "on the road" e.g. if you plan to visit, say, Sächsische Schweiz, then Telekom or Vodafone (and their resellers; D1 or D2) are probably a better bet than O2.

Answer (score 2):

Try the supermarket Netto or Aldi. They have prepaid cards with internet. You must activate the simcard on the marked website.

Comment: Although it's a good idea and probably cheap option, going to a website without a simcard in a foreign country sounds harder than the other answer.

Comment: Most cities have many wiki locations, in (and just outside) coffee shops and in hotels/hostels. So finding a website should not be a problem.

Comment: @Willeke: Also, train stations and airports have free wifi too.

Comment: Also a possibility that once the SIM is installed, it will allow you to access the offering company's own website, or may provide  a captive portal to let you set up.  Certainly works on tablets.