# What is the best way to go from Leipzig/Halle airport to the Leipzig city?

Tags: trains, germany, airports, wifi, leipzig

What public transportation is available to go from Leipzig/Halle (LEJ) Airport to Grimmaischer Steinweg 1, 04103 Leipzig?

It is written on their website that the hotel is a 10-minute walk via the Georgiring from Leipzig’s main railway station.

I will be carrying luggage.

Is there public wifi in Leipzig? If not, what should I do to get an internet connection?

My flight is tomorrow.

Comment: Have you asked your mobile phone provider about data roaming plans ? Much less hassle than getting a new sim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The S5/S5X takes you to Leipzig Hbf in 14 minutes.](https://www.mdf-ag.com/en/passengers-and-visitors/leipzig-halle-airport/arriving-and-departing/train/)

From there it's either a 10 minute walk, as advised, or one stop to [Augustusplatz](https://www.l.de/stadtwerke/privatkunden/kundenservice/webcam/) on any of the trams 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16 or 34 (and some others):

[image]

You can use a single ticket from the airport to anywhere in the inner city, you do not need to get a new ticket for the tram.

You can use Google Maps, Apple Maps or [bahn.de](https://int.bahn.de/en) to plan your journey.

[LEJ airport has free Wifi](https://www.mdf-ag.com/en/passengers-and-visitors/leipzig-halle-airport/services/), [as does Leipzig Hbf](https://www.bahnhof.de/en/leipzig-hbf), and your hotel will *probably* too. As for mobile internet, it probably makes the most sense to get a prepaid SIM card for your phone; see [German SIM card for a two-week visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149834/287) There isn't a lot of retail at LEJ, and it doesn't look like any of the shops that exist there are phone shops. However, there's at least a [Telekom store](https://maps.app.goo.gl/diJBCXRMnzfCxXJU6) and [freenet/mobilcom store](https://maps.app.goo.gl/TChQ1xBSGaMSiz849) at Leipzig Hbf, so you can get a card there. If you want more options you can shop around further in the city centre near your hotel, but if you just want to get set up quickly, this is probably it.

Comment: Saturn at Hauptbahnhof should also have SIM cards.

Comment: Yes, but I’m not sure if they can help you get set up immediately (id verification etc.), and if you don’t feel like mucking around with this yourself, a service store is the better option.